# Как активировать функцию, только при нажатии кнопки интерфейса?

Tags: python, tkinter

Во время практики, я попробовал создать калькулятор с интерфейсом на стандартной библиотеке.

Проблема: есть кнопка `one_but` и к ней через `one_but = Button (command = num(1))` прикрепил функцию

```
def num(s):
    global n
    if n == 0:
        n += s
        label2.config(text = n)
```

Всё остальное в принципе не важно. При компиляции, у меня сразу же s принимает значение 1 и поскольку у меня стандартно у n стоит 0 то к нему прибавляется один, абсолютно тоже самое и с другими кнопками. Как сделать так чтобы s, принимало значение 1 или другое, только при нажатии?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
...
def num(s):
    global n
    if n == 0:
        n += s
        label2.config(text = n)
one_but = Button (command = lambda:num(1))
...
```